# API set up in a way that completion emails contain the combined PDF

Tags: docusignapi

How can I set up my API in a way that completion emails contain the combined PDF instead of two separate files (signed document + certificate of completion)?

I tried searching in the settings but couldn't find it. Do we need to specify it somehow in the JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. CoC ([Certificate of Completion](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=oeq1643226594604&topicId=gpa1578456339545.html&_LANG=enus)) is always separate in the emails.

You can submit your feedback to DocuSign in this matter (and any other matter) by going to https://feedback.docusign.com/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it is a disappointment to me.